# Question about Rademacher system

Tags: real-analysis

Why is the Rademacher system not complete? We have $r_n(x) = \text{sign}(\sin2^n\pi x)$ for $n \geq 0$. The Rademacher system is $\{r_n\}_{n \geq 0}$. I know that the system is not complete, so there has to exist an $f$ such that $\langle f, r_n \rangle = 0$ for all $n \geq 0$. I have seen some questions mention that such an $f$ that could work would be $f=r_1 r_2$, but I am unsure how to verify this. It seems that this function splits the interval $[0,1]$ into $[0,1/4]\cup[1/4,3/4]\cup[3/4,1]$, where $f$ would be $-1$ on the middle interval and $1$ on the others. I am not sure how this implies that the product with any other $r_n$ would make the integral vanish.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the Rademacher system?

Comment: @ArcticChar: Sorry about that, just updated the post.

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1018464/27978

Comment: @copper.hat: Yes I saw this, but they do not go over the details showing why this is true which is where I am stuck.

Comment: You need to do a little work. First sketch $r_1 \cdot r_2$. Then compute the inner product with $r_0,r_1,r_2$. It should be clear why the inner product with $r_k$ for $k \ge 3$ is zero.

Comment: @copper.hat: Agh, of course, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @HrafnMagnus Good luck :-). Sometimes we just need a little nudge.